# How to get selected parent category into the edit form?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I will try to selected parent category but I failed. Please some one give me solution how can i selected parent catgory into edit form?

**Migration**

```php
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
    $table->string("name");
    $table->string("slug");
    $table->string("icon")->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Model**

```php
public function parent() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

**Edit form**

```php
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-line {{ $errors->has('categories')? 'focused error':'' }}">
        <label>Select Category</label>
        <select name="category"
                class="form-control js-example-basic-single select2-hidden-accessible"
                style="width:100%" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
            @forelse($categories as $category)
                <option
                        @foreach ($categories as $parent)
                        {{ $category->parent_id === $parent->parent_id ? 'selected':'' }}
                        @endforeach
                        value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}
                </option>
                @empty
                    <option disabled>No categories found!!!</option>
            @endforelse
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```php
public function edit($id)
{
    $category = Category::findOrFail($id);
    $categories = Category::all();

    return view('admin.category.edit', compact('category', 'categories'));
}
```

Also, I have one problem. When I edit the child category and remove the parent id, it will set own id into parent_id. How can i solve this problem?

**Controller**

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $category = Category::findOrFail($id);
    $validate = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|string|unique:categories,name'.$category->id,
        'icon' => 'bail|required|string',
        'category' => 'nullable:'
    ]);
    if ($validate->fails()) {
        return back()->with('toast_error', $validate->messages()->all()[0])->withInput();
    }

    $slug = Str::slug($request->name);
    $category->parent_id = $request->category;
    $category->name = $request->name;
    $category->slug = $slug;
    $category->icon = $request->icon;
    $category->save();

    return redirect(route('admin.categories.index'))->with('toast_success', 'Category successfully updated..');
}
```

What is my problem with the update function code?

Comment: Don't post your code as images. It's text; copy and paste it into the question.

Comment: As a sidenote, your variable naming may (actually probably *will*) cause an issue here. If you already have `$category` (the `Category` you're editing), you probably don't want to do `@forelse($categories AS $category)`, since `$category->parent_id == $category->id` is now comparing it to itself. You should probably do `@forelse($categories AS $parent)`, then `$parent->id == $category->parent_id`.

Comment: @TimLewis brother didn't solved with your solution..

Comment: Hmm, it should have. Can you edit your question to include the updated code?

Comment: @TimLewis include updated code bro.. check pleae

Comment: Yup, you're still referencing the wrong variable: `value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}`, both of those should now be `$parent->id` and `$parent->name`. And you've got a nested `@forelse ... @foreach`, that doesn't seem necessary. I'll write an answer. 1 sec.

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding your variable `$category`, you don't want to do this. Change your code to the following:

```
<select name="category" class="form-control js-example-basic-single select2-hidden-accessible" style="width:100%" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    @forelse($categories as $parent)
    <option {{ $parent->id == $category->parent_id ? 'selected':'' }} value="{{ $parent->id }}">{{ $parent->name }}</option>
    @empty
    <option disabled>No categories found!!!</option>
    @endforelse
</select>
```

The basic issue is that if you override `$category` via `foreach($categories AS $category)`, then any subsequent calls to `$category` will reference the most recent record from `$categories`, and not the original `$category` record (the result of `$category = Category::findOrFail($id);`).

Inside the loop, you only reference `$category` to compare to `$parent`, but all other references need to be `$parent` (`$parent->id` and `$parent->name`) to avoid setting the incorrect value and display.

Edit: Also, a suggestion, consider using this query instead:

```
$categories = Category::where('id', '!=', $id)->get();
```

The way you have it currently, you allow setting a `$category->parent_id` that matches `$category->id`, and I doubt you want to allow a record to be it's own parent.

Comment: Can you solve my second problem which are included this question?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your other error is. Can you try to explain it better?

Comment: When I edit child category and remove the parent id from this it will set own id into parent_id. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Ah I see. It *might* be an issue with your rule: `'category' => 'nullable:'` (that `:` on the end shouldn't be there), and then you can set `$category->parent_id = $request->input("category", null);`. But beyond that, it shouldn't set it to `$category->id` unless something else weird is going on.